# Не создаются записи в БД

Tags: python, mysql, wordpress, база-данных, pymysql

Кто-нибудь знает, в чем может быть дело? С помощью библиотеки pymysql и python подключаюсь к БД, все ок. Создаю запись, код отрабатывает без ошибок, но в бд ничего не появляется. Пробовал со всеми необходимыми полями, типо post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content и тд. Такое происходит после переезда на бегет. Возможно, что-то нужно установить на самом бегете?

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='...beget.tech',
                       user='',
                       passwd='',
                       db='',
                       charset='')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_title) VALUES ("Первый")')
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Выкинь это немедленно! https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/, https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb

Comment: Мне нужно именно через python добавлять записи

Comment: А Вы уверены, что оператор *pymysql.connect(...)*  действительно отработал? А то он выглядит очень странно. И ещё - а таблица *wp_posts* действительно существует? И у Вас есть права на запись в эту таблицу?

Comment: Да, права есть, таблица есть. Более того если несколько записей создавать и выводить у каждой id, то id, относительно уже имеющихся в бд до импорта записей, определяются верно.

Comment: Когда использовался другой сервер не бегет.ю все работало как надо. Сейчас таже бд, тот же код, но переехал на бегет и ничего не работает. Возможно что-то на сервер устанавливал давно, уже забыл

Comment: Да хоть через что. Есть АПИ и именно его надо юзать, а не прописывать данные к базе  в своём приложении. Кроме того у ВП есть механизм "пароль для приложений". Его тоже стоит использовать.

Comment: Автокоммит там включен? А то может надо вручную коммитить, а без коммита всё записанное обратно роллбэкается. Ну, либо вы не в ту базу пишете, которую потом проверяете.

Comment: не знаю что такое автокоммит) Задал вопрос в поддержку